# How to write to a text file - HttpConnection J2ME

Tags: java, java-me, midp, httpconnection

I get no errors but my code is not saving any new data to the text file, here is my code:

```
public void saveToLeaderboard() throws IOException {
        String toSave = "Random info I want to save";
        HttpConnection connection = null;

        connection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open("EXTERNAL URL", Connector.READ_WRITE, true);
        connection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);

        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(connection.openDataOutputStream());
        out.writeUTF(toSave);        

        out.flush();
        connection.close();
    }
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My own solution at the end of the day :**

I created a server side file (in my case it was a .Net file [.aspx]), I set my external url to call my .Net page with url variables that holds my data needed.

And did a basic save to txt file with server code (in my case C#).

```
public void saveToLeaderboard() throws IOException {
        String toSave = "Data to save";
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        HttpConnection connection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open("External Url" + "?info=" + toSave, Connector.READ_WRITE, true);
        connection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
        inputStream = connection.openInputStream();
        inputStream.close();
        connection.close();
    }
```

Comment: Nice but that was what I suggested. You need to get input stream or response code from your connection.

Comment: Thanks anyway, but you made suggestions what methods or structure of flow I can use. At the end of the day I kept my same code but changed the url to target my server side C# page instead of trying to edit the text file directly.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any FileOutputStream in your code. How is DataOutputStream supposed to write a file?

Answer (score 0):

To actually trigger an HTTP request you need to get any information about the HTTP response, such as the response body using `URLConnection.getInputStream()` or `URLConnection.getResposeCode()` and so on.

See [How HTTP request works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2793153/945945) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Better you try the following coding snippet

```
public void saveToLeaderboard() {

    String toSave = "Random info I want to save";
    HttpConnection connection = null;
    int response_code=HttpConnection.HTTP_OK-1;
    FileConnection fc=null;
    DataOutputStream dos=null;
    DataOutputStream out
    InputStream dis=null; 
    try
    {    
    connection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open("EXTERNAL URL");
    connection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);

     out= connection.openDataOutputStream();
    out.writeUTF(toSave);        

    out.flush();
    response_code=connection.getResponseCode();

    if(response_code==HttpConnection.HTTP_OK)
    {
       dis=connection.openDataInputStream();
       int ch;

       fc=(FileConnection)Connector.open(path,Connector.READ_WRITE); //path is a path of the file to be saved 
       fos=fc.openDataOutputStream(); byte temp; while((ch=dis.read()) !=-1) 
       { 
           temp=(byte)ch; fos.write(temp); 
       } 
       fos.flush(); 
     } 
      else 
       { //Status code not ok }

    }
    catch(ConnectionNotFoundException cnex){//Connection not found} 
    catch(IOException cnex){//ioe exception} 
    catch(Exception cnex){//exception} 


    if(out!=null)
    {
       try{
           out.close();
       }
       catch(Exception cnex){//exception} 
    }  
    if(dis!=null)
    {
       try{
           dis.close();
       }
       catch(Exception cnex){//exception} 
    }  
    if(connection!=null)
    {
       try{
           connection.close();
       }
       catch(Exception cnex){//exception} 
    }  
   if(fos!=null)
    {
       try{
           fos.close();
       }
       catch(Exception cnex){//exception} 
    }
```